# SuiteCloud IDE on Eclipse (Both latest versions) - Hash md5 errors

Tags: eclipse, md5

I have just downloaded the latest version of Eclipse, and I'm trying to install SuiteCloud IDE on it. I have tried both versions, however both are giving me an error when installing.

The error is displayed as below.

Would anyone have suggestions on how to fix this error? It's coming up after the installation dialog. After it downloads the latest version and such. I have tried disabling and removing the firewall and anti-virus.

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
>   session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
>   Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.netsuite.ide.core,2014.1.0.e4.
>   MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 9c8668ad1cb884c421deb5a38fe1233d and found 4d9a0b0c69659466feab1170f1b4beae.
>   Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.netsuite.ide.eclipse.app,2014.1.0.e4.
>   MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 7c375079316e41fb84668c8f12f81662 and found ad1425264d6be52f758525ee2a0831a1.
>   Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.netsuite.ide.eclipse.app.feature,2014.1.0.e4.
>   MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 0d452ca1779ac5874742e01396d6b551 and found b66cbdfc9e13b67416f13eb179dc8ae7.
>   Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.netsuite.ide.eclipse.db,2014.1.0.e4.
>   MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 107c04a4f4a552b368a3d54f2f6057c4 and found b89fcc9a2d23a426187d91a6a522eb2d.
>   Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.netsuite.ide.eclipse.db.feature,2014.1.0.e4.
>   MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: e34fa423269412d2373cfb1779fc8f7f and found 4fee6ed027616904ceba991bc26c3349.
>   Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.netsuite.ide.eclipse.debugger,2014.1.0.e4.
>   MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 390cbd5a719b49fb3c52a131d60aae84 and found 08ebd037ba076f63ff4282c6429fd502.
>   Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.netsuite.ide.eclipse.debugger.feature,2014.1.0.e4.
>   MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 1810c724bde13c488b371312ca719a14 and found 656ed3c2692737efa80691fc9630149e.
>   Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.netsuite.ide.eclipse.feature,2014.1.0.e4.
>   MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 7501eedf0b7ef2b21c4943704552c9d9 and found 41b6ee68f10e61bd0e9beea6983b6c97.
>   Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.netsuite.ide.eclipse.help,2014.1.0.e4.
>   MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: fb5775ee872568657aad235002ae02e0 and found 10efe54af1abce657bb74d104ab9cebd.
>   Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.netsuite.ide.eclipse.help.feature,2014.1.0.e4.
>   MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: ecffd396944a1617c6127334241516fc and found b4e815106068e8be83bdbf7403749c16.
>   Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.netsuite.ide.eclipse.lib,2014.1.0.e4.
>   MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 1463b2b504f8278b59fb5b0c3da71132 and found 5f78437326e2fee67ea0d75fa6d9459d.
>   Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.netsuite.ide.eclipse.lib.feature,2014.1.0.e4.
>   MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: d0de62ae88500189bcf5ac61e0a0adae and found 6a9edeb13d508bd45de5f11eb18c4d64.
>   Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.netsuite.ide.eclipse.ws,2014.1.0.e4.
>   MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: e0cf2aa12d5c3b8150d26e31a5159728 and found d934c639d1b5ad863baaafa4527737b1.
>   Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.netsuite.ide.eclipse.ws.feature,2014.1.0.e4.
>   MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 0fee946184e7e5efbf2ff450ca919be5 and found 4a16e8bd51126d1d0f7b863f083ca329.
>   Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.netsuite.ide.tools,2014.1.0.e4.
>   MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: efe1dc55f74258ee0626fb241d82d12f and found d10179a2d5502c260d4e8ef59a94078b.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can try changing http to https for the link. Another scenario is that your proxy or firewall is misbehaving. Try connecting and downloading the IDE on a network without proxy or just try downloading with another network.